# Vector algebra in tetrad formalism

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, notation

Working with general relativistic model of binary NS system and came upon usage of tetrads. My team uses orthonormal Schwarzschild tetrad and so:
$\boldsymbol{\gamma_{\hat{i}}}\cdot\boldsymbol{\gamma_{\hat{j}}}=\eta_{\hat{i}\hat{j}}$

Here, hatted indices are tetrad indices and \eta is Minkovski metric tenzor.
Does it mean, that explicit componentwise form of dot and cross products will be the same as in Minkovski metric?

(e.g., $\boldsymbol{A}\cdot\boldsymbol{B}=-A^{\hat{0}}B^{\hat{0}}+A^{\hat{1}}B^{\hat{1}}+...$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed, that's the point of using the tetrad. It's an orthonormal basis, so you trade convenience when taking derivatives and the like (because you don't have a coordinate basis anymore) for convenience in dot products.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what drawbacks will I have with derivatives?

Comment: @Tajimura You can only directly calculate partial derivatives, so if greek indices are coodinate indices, and latin indices are tetrad indices, then to calculate something like $\partial_a V^b$, you need to actually calculate $e^\mu_a \partial_\mu V^b$ for some arbitrary coordinate system. The tetrad "diractional derivatives" $\partial_a$ do not commute (unlike actual partials), so we have $[\partial_a, \partial_b]=C^c_{\ ab}\partial_c$, where the $C$ are the frame commutation relations. For this reason, derivatives are usually calculated in coordinate basis...

Comment: @Tajimura ... and differential forms notation is used on them.

Comment: @Uldreth shouldn't vierbein be inside the derivative there? Meaning, if I want to take a partial over, say, r (coordinate) from $V^{\hat{\mu}}$ shall I take the derivative first, and then multiply by $e_{\hat{\mu}}^{r}$ vierbein, or first multiply $V^{\hat{\mu}}$ by vierbein and then take a derivative?